# How To Edit Categories Page In PrestaShop

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I want to customize the categories page and place the categories which are in the navigation to be placed in the left sidebar.

I have given a screen shot

Any help would be appreciated

Left side bar presta,

[image]

Comment: What did you try? Do you have any développement skills? This question lacks minimum code to help you. Don't understand why it has been upvoted.